# GridView During Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have an application in which you add file locations into radgridviews.

To create the gridviews there is a button which Creates a new tab with a gridview in it.

```
Resources = new RadPageViewPage();
ResourcesGridView = new RadGridView();

TabContainer.Controls.Add(Resources);
Resources.Controls.Add(ResourcesGridView);
```

etc.

The problem is that they all end up with the same name and if i want to acquire data from the gridview it always takes it from the last gridview.

I tried to generate a name for them by doing things like

```
ResourcesGridView.Name = "Resources" + ResourceCount + "Grid";
```

But yeah if that did work i don't really know how to access that name as this sort of thing isn't going to work.

```
("" + TabContainer.SelectedPage.Name.ToString() + "Grid").Rows ........
```

So i'm a little bit stumped on how to generate and use a name for the GridViews.

Answer (score 0):

can you use a control array?